# What the meaning of 'in the trace sense'?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rsGt.png)

There are always descriptions about the value of boundary. I want to know if this condition is necessary.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways you can require your solution to take a value on the boundary (say zero). So you can require that the limit of the solution at the boundary be equal to zero at each point (assuming you approach the point from inside the region). Or you can require that $Tr(u)=0$, which is a weaker requirement, since $Tr(u)$ is in a Lebesgue space (typically $L^{1/2}$). This is what the phrase "in the trace sense" means.